# Pegar Texto de URL de Site Externo

Tags: php

Preciso pegar o texto entre as tags a de um site:
`<a href="">Este Texo</a>`

Estou conseguindo pegar seu `href` com este código:

```
        $dadosSite = file_get_contents($utl);
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        @$dom->loadHTML($dadosSite);
        $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        foreach ($links as $link)
        {
            $termo = 'video';
            $pattern = '/' . $termo . '/';
            if (preg_match($pattern, $link->getAttribute('href')))
            {
                echo $link->getAttribute('href');

            }
        }
```

Comment: Utilize `$link->textContent;` para capturar o valor do conteúdo da tag.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Show de bola, perfeito